# Incoming linked servers information in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there anyway that we can list out the linked servers coming to a SQL server? I am trying to catch all the connections coming to a SQL Server. Please help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute prcoedure: sp_linkedservers 
[MSFT article describing this procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189519.aspx)

or maybe if you want more info:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.Servers a
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.linked_logins b ON b.server_id = a.server_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals c ON c.principal_id = b.local_principal_id
```